# Reading data from a external list using a 2010 workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, sql-server, external-content-type, external-list

I work with SharePoint 2013, and need to read information from a external list that I have created. The list can display information correctly when using it through the browser.

I need to create a workflow that will use this information. Since I found that 2013 workflows cannot interact with External Lists, I am using 2010 workflows. I can configure the workflow as usual, select the fields I would like to retrieve and apply the filters, etc. But when I run the workflow, it finishes correctly without getting any data from the external list. No errors, it just returns nothing. I have tried to print it in the log, save the data in another field, in a variable... Always empty.

Is there any reason why I can see the information in the list, while the workflow can't read it? I know the information is not actually stored in SharePoint, but can't the workflow find the information by querying the list?

Comment: When you say "external" list, is that another list in the same site? In the same site collection? Same webapp? Also, what type of column are you doing your lookup on to get the list item?

Comment: A external list created through a external content type, coming from a sql server view. This external list is created in the same site where I am running my workflow, same site collection, same web app. Otherwise, I would not be able to query it with my workflow. Trying to query normal list information like text or numbers. This is not an standard lookup to another list in the site.